# Relationship between height and mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity

> Objects with different masses are placeed on the horizontal surface of a table. The objects are then raised to different heights above the tabel. The gain in gravitational potential energy of each object is the same. What would the graph look like between the variation of the height h of the objects above the table with their mass m?

Consider the problem above.

Here's my understanding. Gravitational potential energy is $E=mgh$. Hence an object with more mass will be raised to less height, when the change in gravitational potential energy is constant. That is if the mass doubles, the height simultaneulsy halves and so on. Hence shouldn't the graph be of the form $y=mx$ where $m$ is a constant, so a negative linear trend? However the answers show a graph that has a negative curve. What's going on here?

Comment: "when the change in gravitational potential energy is constant", so $h=\frac{E}{mg}=\frac{k}{m},\;\;\;k=E/g$

Comment: *Hence…* In $y=mx$, does $y$ halve when $x$ doubles? No, it doesn’t, so your conclusion is false.

Comment: Try plotting some sample values if you're having trouble with your intuitions about the data not matching the algebraic result.

Comment: What's going on is that you're mistakenly equating "inversely proportional" to "linear with a negative slope" :) Linear (through zero, with a negative slope) means - if you choose some $x$, then $y$ will be $x$ times some constant. The bigger the $x$, the bigger the drop. And it's below the x-axis. That's still just *proportional*, but the sign is negative. E.g., if $x = 1/4$, then $y$ will drop in proportion to $1/4$.  But when things are *inversely proportional*, an $x$ of $1/4$ corresponds to a $y$ of $4$ times some constant. That is, it's proportional to $x^{-1}$.